# get and post in one action do different stuff - is it OK?

Tags: php, architecture, kohana

I'm using Kohana's routing with the route being defined as `domain/controller/action`. To demonstrate my question let's consider sign-in flow. Currently, if I want to sign-in user I need to return form first and then proceed with data sent by user. Do I need to have two actions, each for the corresponding flow (returning flow and proceeding with user data), or it can be done with one action by differentiating between POST and GET requests? I have one action now which returns form template if GET request is made and proceeds with signing in if POST request is made, but I question that architecture. Here is the sample of code:

```
public function action_signUp() {
    if (HTTP_Request::POST == $this->request->method()) {
        //proceed with user sent data
    } else if (HTTP_Request::GET == $this->request->method()) {
        //return form template
    }
}
```

Comment: in one action you can only use one method post/get for this you need to fire two action one for get and one for post or you need to arrange in one action by conditionally

Comment: _or you need to arrange in one action by conditionally_ - that's what I'm doing, but I'm questioning that architecture

Comment: for this you need to be more specific and show some code what you do and need